# How do I create a dummy column in R that matches the length of other columns with static value?

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable, kable

I have a dataframe

```
> FactAdWordsCampaignDaily
    AdwordsCampaignId SearchBudgetLostImpressionShare SearchExactMatchImpressionShare SearchImpressionShare
1           177373599                    2.504690e-01                       0.6740812             0.6801126
2           177373599                    4.149378e-02                       0.8863636             0.8858921
3           177373599                    0.000000e+00                       0.8998836             0.9000000
4           177373599                    0.000000e+00                       0.9039242             0.9007732
5           177373599                    0.000000e+00                       0.9381818             0.9378238
```

I want to create 5th column called AveragePosition where all values are 0. Everyday the number of rows in FactAdWordsCampaignDaily can from 5 to 15 to 70. its random, but I want AveragePostion to always have value 0 for all of its rows and it should be same length as other rows everyday.

I tried-

```
import kable
    FactAdWordsCampaignDaily <- fastDummies::dummy_cols(FactAdWordsCampaignDaily, select_columns = "AveragePostion")
    knitr::kable(FactAdWordsCampaignDaily)
```

But got 10101 as output. I just want it to be 0 throughout. Any solutions?

Comment: Try `FactAdWordsCampaignDaily$AveragePosition <- 0`. It doesn’t sound like [dummy codes](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-dummy-coding/) are what you’re looking for. I’m also a bit confused by your question (`import kable` isn’t valid R code…)

Comment: it worked thanks. new to R was following this kable cran example https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastDummies/vignettes/making-dummy-variables.html